# Showing data from List with class in C#

Tags: list

I am trying to show data from list that has user defined type data.

Here is my class

```
namespace test
{
class Employee
{
    private string employeeName;
    private string employeeId;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Employee Name: " + EmployeeName + "\nEmployee ID: " + EmployeeId;
    }

    public string EmployeeName
    {
        get { return employeeName; }
        set { employeeName = value;}
    }

    public string EmployeeId
    {
        get { return employeeId; }
        set { employeeId = value;}
    }
}
}
```

And here is my Main method,

```
namespace test
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Employee employees = new Employee();
        List<Employee> listEmployee = new List<Employee>();

        employees.EmployeeName = "TEST 1";
        employees.EmployeeId = "01";

        listEmployee.Add(employees);

        employees.EmployeeName = "TEST 2";
        employees.EmployeeId = "02";

        listEmployee.Add(employees);

        Console.WriteLine("Number of Employee in the list: "+ listEmployee.Count);
        Console.WriteLine();

        foreach (Employee em in listEmployee)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(em);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

     }
}
}
```

The output supposed to show,

```
Number of Employee in the list: 2

Employee Name: TEST 1
Employee ID: 01

Employee Name: TEST 2
Employee ID: 02
```

But it shows,

```
Number of Employee in the list: 2

Employee Name: TEST 2
Employee ID: 02

Employee Name: TEST 2
Employee ID: 02
```

Please tell me why I am not getting the expected output and how to overcome that.

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Chen greatly answered your question, but I would also suggest (for later code review) to rename your "employees" variable to "employee" and "listemployee" to "listOfEmployees" or just "employees"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have misunderstandings about `object` and `reference`.

You add an object, i.e. `employees` into the list:

[image]

Here the first element of the list holds the `reference` to the `object`. Hence when you make changes on the object, it becomes

[image]

Then you insert the object into the list again, and therefore the second position of the list also holds the reference to `employees`.

[image]

You should create a new object (with a new reference) before adding it to list -

```
Employee employees2 = new Employee();
employees2.EmployeeName = "TEST 2";
employees2.EmployeeId = "02";

listEmployee.Add(employees2);
```

Comment: Thank You Chen. Now I am clear. Thank you again for spending time to draw all those graphics for just to make me clear. You are Awesome!!!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your Modified main

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Employee employeeFirst = new Employee();
    List<Employee> listEmployee = new List<Employee>();

    employeeFirst.EmployeeName = "TEST 1";
    employeeFirst.EmployeeId = "01";

    listEmployee.Add(employeeFirst);

    Employee employeeNext = new Employee();


    employeeNext.EmployeeName = "TEST 2";
    employeeNext.EmployeeId = "02";

    listEmployee.Add(employeeNext);

    Console.WriteLine("Number of Employee in the list: "+ listEmployee.Count);
    Console.WriteLine();

    foreach (Employee em in listEmployee)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(em);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

 }
```

Comment: Darrell, Thank you a lot. :)

Comment: Aprreciated , Enjoy :-)